# Stuck between TTY1 and Disconnected from Plymouth

Tags: boot, fglrx, plymouth

I am running 12.04 with an HD7970. I installed fglrx from AMD and it worked okay. Then Ubuntu prompted me to install updates (from software-center). After doing this, the PC only boots to a black screen called Chips tty1.

If I go to the recovery mode, all the options give me a blinking cursor (after a confirmation dialog), but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> then they react (repair, gfx safe) and shortly after it reboots.

If I choose the normal boot, I get an orange

> "Mountall: Plymouth disconnected".

Answer (score 2):

Follow these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm  
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
```

(I ran this command above, but was told by the system to use `# sudo apt-get autoremove` instead, after the `#sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm` command.)

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

select GDM when prompted

```
sudo reboot
```

That fixed it for me :)